# how can a light sensor be used to read colors, in particular red

Tags: lego-mindstorms, nxt

how can a light sensor be used to read colors, in particular red. I don't have a color sensor, I have a light sensor. how can i use light sensor instead of color sensor

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question at all and no code has been supplied.

Answer (score 1):

When using a light sensor, you are able to use red color-filter, placed in front of a light sensor, to detect red light only.

Colors filters will filter the colors of incoming light, making it so only red light would be visible to the light sensor.

A color filter would probably be sold separately from a light sensor, although you could probably do some shopping around to find cheap examples.